# Casting DB2 column to accept multi lingual characters in Open query

Tags: sql-server, db2, db2-400

I am using open query to retrieve data from IBM db2 to SQL server.

Below is the sample query used

```
select top 10 * from OpenQuery(Link server, 'Select columnName from table where column2=15'  )
```

The columnName needs to be converted / cast in Unicode format to accept multi lingual characters. How to use **casting in the inner query**?

My issue is similar to that of https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/997384/linker-server-to-as400-db2-character-translation-problems

I want to retrieve the data in Thai and Chinese characters. I have rows of data which are to be in Thai and Chinese characters. But the data shows as garbled when I use the command which I have provided. The column type in sql server is defined as nvarchar.

Answer (score 0):

Cast your column with the CCSID code xxxx corresponding to your language :

> select cast(columnName as char(14) CCSID xxxx) from ...

Comment: Hi. what should be the CCSID number ?

Comment: Depends on the main CCSID of your IBM i, and depends on the column definition. See [CCSID IBM i] (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzsidvals.htm)

Comment: There are a few CCSID's that you might want to choose from. 1208 is the CCSID for UTF-8, 1200 is the CCSID for UTF-16, and, for completeness, 13488 is the CCSID for UCS-2, though UCS-2 has been superseded by UTF-16. UTF-32 is not supported by a CCSID.